# I need a command that redoes filter-repo

Tags: android, git, github, project

I needed to remove a video file that was 160mb a few commits ago, in the current commit it no longer existed, searching I found the following command `git filter-repo --force --path myapp/app/src/main/res/ raw/intro.mp4` when executing my commits simply disappeared, it's as if I was returned to the commit of this file and the rest is gone, can anyone explain to me what happened and how can I recover my project?

With this command I expected to delete the specific file from my git history, but what happened was to delete everything I did after that file.

Answer (score 1):

What happened?

There is a [`--invert-path`](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html) option, which turns `--path` into an exclude list.

Unfortunately, the command you mention in your question has done the reverse: only keep that mp4 file in he history of your repo.

How can I recover my project ?

Check your reflog : `git reflog` or `git reflog my/branch`, but chances are `git filter-repo` emptied it.

Your next option is to check if you have a mention of the sha of one of your original commits (higher up in your terminal window? in a log message?), or run `git fsck` to view what commits you can recover.